# Adding values to a specific property in an array(?) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im wondering how I can add a value to to main in this array.

```
var herpderp = {
    "main": ["stuff", "stuff"]
};
```

so it would look like:

```
var herpderp = {
    "main": ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3"]
};
```

Preferably I'd like to create this kind of structure from a couple of strings in a fucntion if that's possible. So says I have this

```
var strings = {"stuff1","stuff2", "stuff3"}
for (each element of strings) {
    what do I do here to get the structure above
}
```

Alternatively another function to search through an Array of objects on a specifik property. Right now Im trying to use this to filter through the array, maybe there's another way?

```
var arrays = search;
var result = events.filter(function(item) {
    for (var prop in arrays)
        if (arrays[prop].indexOf(item[prop]) == -1)
            return false;
    return true;
});
```

Thank you kindly for any reply!

Comment: [Here's how you access properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). You use the [`push` method for adding things to arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). I'd suggest working through a few JavaScript tutorials until you feel comfortable manipulating objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`herpderp.main` is your array, so you can add to the array like so:

`herpderp.main.push(value)`

If the key for your array was not a valid variable name (it starts with a number, for example), you could use bracket notation instead:

`herpderp['123key'].push(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are changing the previous values beside adding a new element.

```
var herpderp = {
        "main": ["stuff", "stuff"]
};
var strings = ["stuff1","stuff2", "stuff3"];
strings.forEach(function(value,key){
herpderp.main[key] = value;
});
console.log(herpderp);
```